# please explain "#variable" vs "let variable" in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[Code Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whQUr.png)

In the above picture when i use `#course of courses` in `*ngFor` it does not work. If i use `let course of courses` it works. Please explain this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changed from the `Beta` version of Angular 2 to the `RC` version.

Now it's `let` instead of `#` to not mix up with template variables.

Comment: I didn't see your answer while posting mine.